# Logic error in dropdown box based addition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code which is calculating a total based on a selection of checkboxes and a value from the dropdown list.

Here is the HTML

```
<tr>
    <<input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" value="10" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" value="10" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" value="10" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" value="10" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

and for the dropdown box it is like this

```
<select onchange="dropCh(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

this is my javascript to add up the sum, however I am facing a problem with the onchange function in the dropdown, I am unable to figure out how to subtract the old value of selection before using the new value.

```
function clickCh(caller) {
    var total = document.getElementById("total");
    if (caller.checked) {
        add(caller);
    } else {
        subtract(caller);
    }
}

function add(caller) {
    total.value = total.value * 1 + caller.value * 1;
}

function subtract(caller) {
    total.value = total.value * 1 - caller.value * 1;
}

function dropCh(caller) {
    var total = document.getElementById("total");
    total.value = total.value * (1 + caller.value * 0.1);
}
```

I know that I need to add a js code to remove the value before adding the next one while choosing from dropdown option. Can someone tell me which direction to move in.

Comment: NO start `<td>` tags in your markup!

Comment: You've also forgotten the `var total = document.getElementById("total");` in your `add` and `subtract` (they appear to be relying on the automatic global instead -- not a good idea).

Comment: sorry for the horrible copy/paste, but I do have start <td> tags.

Comment: What is the total supposed to be? E.g., what's the formula? You shouldn't have to use the old value, surely `total` should be derived entirely by the chosen inputs?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder they are being called from clickCh which is obtaining the value of total, add and subtract are not being used anywhere else.

Comment: @user3335993: Yes, but `total` is a **local** variable in `clickCh`. `add` and `subtract` don't see that local variable. The only reason you don't get an error is that elements with `id`s automatically create global variables, unless something else shadows them. It's not something you should rely on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder here is the formula : 10 for each checkbox, and if x is the value from dropdown box the total = total*(1 + x*0.1)

Comment: @user3335993: That makes no sense. `total` should be a result, only on the left. It shouldn't be on both sides of the `=`.

Comment: ok let me phrase it like this total = 10*no of checkbox selected + 10*no of checkbox selected*value from dropdown*0.1; I have defined 10*no of checkbox selected as total in clickCh function so it is finaltotal = total(1+x*0.1) where x is the value from dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here is the formula : 10 for each checkbox, and if x is the value from dropdown box the total = total*(1 + x*0.1)

I'm going to assume the `total` on the right-hand side of that `=` is the total of the checkboxes, e.g.:

```
total = (totalOfCheckboxes) * (1 + dropDownValue * 0.1);
```

So on change or click, calculate the total like this:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"); // You may want to limit this selector more
var dropDownValue = +document.getElementById("selectBox").value;      // Add this id to the markup
var i;
var totalOfCheckboxes = 0;
for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        totalOfCheckboxes += +checkboxes[i].value;
    }
}
document.getElementById("total").value = totalOfCheckboxes * (1 + dropDownValue * 0.1);
```

Comment: @user3335993: So deal with that condition. Either by giving the drop-down a default value, or not doing the calculation at all if it doesn't have a value and requires one, or whatever else is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r732b/1/)**

```
function dropCh(caller) {
    var total = document.getElementById("total");
    var value = 0;
    $('td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        value = value + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(value +' '+( 1 + caller.value * 0.1));
    total.value = value * (1 + caller.value * 0.1);
}
```

The above function check the values of checkboxes each time, so even if you uncheck a check box, you will get correct value.